# If statement and && gives IDE error 'Syntax error on token "=", <= expected'

Tags: java, operators

I  have a simple guess number game. It has a function to ask whether you want tips. It saves the response in a `boolean` called `tips` as shown.

```
while (run) {
    while (tinvalidrun){
        System.out.println("Do you want any tips? y or n?");
        input=in.next();
        switch(input){
        case "y":
            System.out.println("Ok, we will tell you how close you are!");
            tinvalidrun=false;
            tips=true;
            break;
        case "n":
            System.out.println("Wanna go hard eh? Well, go along!");
            tinvalidrun=false;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You pressed the wrong key!\nDo you have butter fingers?");
        }
    }
```

Then I have some more code that makes more variables and makes a random number. And finally I get the user input for the guess and test it:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    guess = in.nextByte();
    times++;
    if (guess == gval) {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No luck! Try again!");
        if (tips=true) {
            if (guess < gval) {
                  System.out.println("You are too low!");
            }
            else { 
                System.out.println("You are too high!");
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried putting the `tips=true` and `guess < gval` in one `if` with `&&` but it doesn't work. I did this:

```
if(guess<gval && tips=true)
```

It asks me to replace `=` with `<=` or something like that. I tried using two `if` statements but when you say no, it still shows the tips. I tried looking at the brackets but they look fine. Please Help! If there is any simplification or improvements or ideas I can do to my code, they are welcome.

I have more question as well. It crashes (obviously) when you try to type a letter to the integer. I tried using strings and my `tinvalidrun` loop to avoid this but I can't. Is there a way to do this? 
 Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank You, that fixed it. How can i close this?

Comment: Accept the answer that you like best by clicking on the checkmark to the left; then this question will no longer show as unsolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Testing equality

You need `tips == true`, or just `if (guess<gval && tips)` and `if (tips)` as you are testing a `boolean`.

`=` is an [assignment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1), `==` is an [equality operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21). It is easy to mix the two up, but the difference is enormous...

#### Boolean assignment is also an (unexpected) equality test

You say "*I tried using two if statements but when you say no, it still shows the tips.*". The `if` statement expects an expression which [must have type `boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9). Any assignment expression (i.e. `tips = true`) evaluates as the new value assigned to the variable. From the [JLS §15.26.1 Simple Assignment Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1):

> At run time, **the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred**. The result of an assignment expression is not itself a variable.

Therefore `if (tips = true)` is valid syntax, because `tips = true` is *both* an assignment and also a `boolean` expression which can therefore be used in an `if`.

In your case `tips = true` assigns `true` to `tips` (even if it started out `false`), then returns that new value of `tips`. The `if` sees the new value (`true`) and continues happily on. It is not therefore a test that `tips` was originally `true`. By example, this means that the following prints out the `"Oops!"` text:

```
boolean tips = false;
if (tips=true){
    System.out.println("Oops! This tests as true, but that isn't what we wanted");
}
```

As you can see, conflating assignment and testing is generally a bad idea. It is usually a mistake if you use `=` in an `if`/`do`/`while` expression. Sometimes it can help with brevity but it is generally bad practice.

#### Why doesn't `if (guess<gval && tips = true)` work?

This is due to [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). In the expression `if (guess<gval && tips = true)` the operator precedence is `<` then `&&` and then `=`, so the compiler no longer evaluates the `tips = true` part as an assignment of `true` to tips. You could use brackets to contain `tips = true`, but as I said above you don't really want the assignment so you can ignore this detail <sup>†</sup>.

#### Testing valid byte input

For the last part of your question - you say you get an invalid byte if someone inputs a letter. I'm guessing you get a `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

You can use [`Scanner.hasNextByte()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextByte--) to test if the input is a byte before consuming it. If that returns false you can consume and discard the input using `nextLine()`, print out an error message and loop again.

<sup>†</sup> *Depending on how you were writing your code you may also have seen a message from eclipse such as "The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, Boolean" or from javac such as "error: unexpected type ... required: variable, found: value". None of them tell you much other than your syntax is sufficiently messed up the compiler can't parse it.*

Answer (score 5):

`if(tips = true)` is always `true` condition because *here* we have [assigned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) value `true` to `tips`.

It will first assign tips to true and then *check* will be performed in `if` so your `else` part is *dead* due to this code and control will never ever enter in `else` part.

If you want to check whether `tips` is `true` or not then you can just write `if(tips)` and if you want to check whether it is `false` than you should write `if(tips == false`). Where `==` will check [equality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) while `=` will assign the value or reference.

Comment: Other than that, your answer is the only one that explained what actually happens in the program (until Andy edited his), so it should receive more credit. The others only say "do this!" without any explanation.

Comment: I agree with @MrLister. I have one other comment: "*...check whether it is `false` than (sic) you should write `if(tips == false)`.*", most of us would just write `if(!tips)`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the test for equality operator is `==` not `=`. Secondly, you don't need the operator when testing a boolean. `if (tips) ...` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

`=` and `==` are two completely different things. `=` is the assignment operator and is used to assign values to variables. `==` is the equality operator and is used to check if a variable is equal to a certain value, or equal to another variable.

You should be using `==` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
if(tips=true)
```

single `=` means assigning

This should be

```
if(tips==true)
```

Answer (score 2):

One equal sign is for assigning as you have done in (`guess = in.nextByte();, tinvalidrun=false, tips=true;`, and so..) the value in the RHS variable is "put" to the LHS variable. The become equal, i.e they contains the same value. To compare, use two equals sign operator,comparison operator (`foo1 == foo2`). [several operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a little change, use == instead of =

Instead of

```
if (tips=true)
```

you would have do

```
if (tips==true)
```

Comment: Not so "little" , there is strong algorithmic error in '=' :)

Comment: i know sir, thats why i said change is little but the not error :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Comparison is double `==`, single is assignment.
2. comparison with true is redundancy (but legal)

---

```
if(guess < gval && tips==true)
```

**or**

```
if(guess<gval && tips)
```

Your code fragment doesn't show variable declarations, maybe you compare wrong types too. My fragments assume that tips is `boolean`.